# How Google has an SSL certificate from itself and my browser doesn't give an error

Tags: ssh

I know that I can create my own SSL certificate, but in this case the browser will give 'not trusted' error to the user, as the certificate is not browser trustworthy. So companies go and get an SSL certificate from a third party. But checking the ssh certificate of google, I realized they have certificate from Google Inc.; and my browser does not give an error for it. How is it possible? Did they created a sub company to issue themselves their own SSL certificates?

Answer (score 2):

Google has its own intermediate CA. They have a webpage here https://pki.google.com/

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP already mentioned that (*I realized they have certificate from Google Inc.*)

Comment: "How is it possible? Did they created a sub company to issue themselves their own SSL certificates?" question answered, they have an intermediate CA, details of which can be found in the link.